# Querying Firestore Posts with Multiple Conditions

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on a project where I need to query posts from Firestore based on two conditions. I want to retrieve posts where isPrivate is set to false and then order them by the createdAt field in descending order to get the most recent ones. Here's the code I'm using:

```
const postRef = collection(db, 'Posts');

const querySnap = await query(postRef, where('isPrivate', '==', false), orderBy('createdAt', 'desc'));
```

However, when I try to implement this, my app goes blank upon refresh. After some research, I found that Firestore doesn't allow querying in different fields in a single document. How can I correct my code or structure the query to achieve this functionality without causing issues in my a# # pp?
Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

## **I tried:**

```
const postRef = collection(db, 'Posts');
const querySnap = await query(postRef, where('isPrivate', '==', false), orderBy('createdAt', 'desc'));
```

## **I am Expecting:**

Query posts that are not private, and orderBy recent posts, i have createdAt field in any post, the data in the field is serverTimestamp

Answer (score 1):

When you perform such a query:

```
const querySnap = await query(postRef, where('isPrivate', '==', false), orderBy('createdAt', 'desc'));
```

Please note that Firestore requires an [index](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing). You can create the index manually in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/) or you'll find in the console a message that sounds like this:

```
FAILED_PRECONDITION: The query requires an index. You can create it here: ...
```

You can simply click on that link or copy and paste the URL into a web browser tab and your index will be automatically created for you.

Comment: Hey there. Have you tried my solution above, does it work for you?